# Detect click event on selected tab

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm writing an application for Ionic 3. In the application, I have a tab bar. When I select one of the tabs, the method (ionSelect) is triggered. But when I try to select the same tab again the method does not work.

How to define a click on an already active tab?

```
<ion-tabs tabsPlacement="bottom" tabsLayout="icon-top" #tabs>
    <ion-tab tabIcon="logo-icon" tabTitle="" [root]="contentPage"></ion-tab>
    <ion-tab tabIcon="dots-icon"  tabTitle="title" (ionSelect)="openTabMenuModal()" [root]="customPage"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

Comment: Would you show us some code, please?

Comment: You could use `<ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" (click)='clickedOnTab();></ion-tab>'`

Comment: @RonNabuurs unfortunately no, it does not work

Comment: try this https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/capturing-ion-tab-click-on-active-tab-event/56594/28